# How does the mudra connect the the little red snake with the Bindu

Tags: shiva

Who knows the hand mudra that is used when uniting the little red snake Maha Kundalini Sakti with the red Bindu ?!( This works for me ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oyVj.jpg)( The triple eyed double triangle mudra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGZ4e.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by Red Bindu... Do you mean the central Bindu of Sri Yantram? Also from where did you get the idea that Kundalini is red snake?...

Comment: The red bindu is a symbol worn by many Hindus in the middle of the forehead it is a symbol of remembrance of that activated center of unity and bliss from days gone by. The little red snake also known as a serpent is in the bowl at the base of the spine and is seen by those who have the eye to see. Vineet who commented on " Kundalini the serpent in the bowl gave reference and confirmation via "Dnyaneshwari" by Shri Sant Dnyanshwar who is believed to be a great Yogi as confined by Swift Pushkar.

Comment: there is no magic. Mudras are not magic. Scripture only says to a comfortable position with the left hand below the right.

Comment: Ya magic and miracles are only given power and acknowledged by those who do not know. Comfortable position with left hand below the right sounds good to me. Will post a pic of a triple eye double triangle mudra that I know.

Comment: Red bindu is worn by only those who believe in rebirth

Comment: The red Bindu is seen and its Bliss felt by those who have awakened the Ajna chakra.

Answer (score 4):

There is no single Mudra that will "connect the Kundalini Devi with the red dot Bindu."

You need to understand that after completing the task of creation Mahadevi (or the Mother Goddess) sleeps in each Jiva (or take rest to be more appropriate).

The place where she sleeps, like a coiled snake, is near the root Chakra, the lowest or first among the seven Chakras, called [the Muladhara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muladhara). She covers there the mouth of the Sushumna Nadi while sleeping.

> In it is the Supreme Goddess Kundalini of the form of electricity, in
>   a coil. It has three coils and half (like a serpent) and is in the
>   mouth of the Sushumna.
>
> **Shiva Samhita 2.23**

And, the place in between the eyebrows, where that red dot is worn by the devotees, is the place for another Chakra called [Ajna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajna).

Success in Yoga is said to be attained when the sleeping Goddess is awakened. Once the Kundalini Shakti recovers awareness and the Yogi moves it upwards through the channel of Sushumna, one by one all the Chakras are mastered and pierced. In this way, the Goddess gradually moves up to meet Parashiva, who stays in the highest Chakra called the Sahsrara.

And, to awaken the Kundalini, practice of some advanced Mudras are recommended in Yogic scriptures like Shiva Samhita, Hatha Yoga Pradipika and also in the Tantras.

> When the sleeping Goddess Kundalini is  awakened, through the grace of
>   Guru, then all the lotuses and the bonds are readily pierced through
>   and through.
>
> Therefore, in order that the Goddess, who is asleep in the mouth of
>   the Brahmarandhra (the innermost hollow of Sushumna) be awakened, the
>   Mudras to be practised with greatest care.
>
> **Shiva Samhita 4.13-14**

The names of the Mudras, given in the very next verse (4.15) are: 1. Mahamudra 2. Mahabandha 3. Mahabhedha 4. Khechari 5. Jalandhara 6. Mulabandha 7. Viparitakarana 8. Uddana 9. Vajrondi 10. Shaktichalana.

After learning the Mudras (note that none of these Mudras are Hasta Mudras/Hand gestures) from the Guru, and mastering them by practice, one can successfully awaken the sleeping Goddess and make her move towards the Ajna Chakra and even further above.

So, to answer your question, there is no way to connect Mahakundali with the red dot (in your words).

But, there are Yogic ways of moving the Kundalini Shakti to move upwards piercing the Ajna Chakra (where that dot is worn).

EDIT:

> Who knows the hand mudra ... ?

Again there is no single Hasta Mudra that is effective for the given purpose.

One Mudra that I know about, which is said to agitate the sleeping Kundalini Shakti, is done as the image given below shows:

[image]

It is called the Kundalini Mudra. (Image taken from [this site](https://www.yogaenred.com/en/2013/07/24/mudras-kundalini-mudra/)).

But obviously we can't expect that with the help of this Mudra alone we can make the Kundalini rise upto the Ajna Chakra. Had it been that easy, great Yogis would have been commoner than thieves and humbugs in this world.

EDIT2:

[image]

The pic you have added now is of a Mudra called the **Shakti Mudra**. It is one of the Mudras that relate to Mother Goddess. It has many benefits I know about but how is it useful in "connecting the Kundalini with the Red dot"?

Comment: Will send a pic of a triple eyed double triangle hand mudra that I know.

Comment: I would call it Maha Kundalini Sakti Mudra, it is probably one of many Sakti Mudras. This mudra occurred spontaniously and it is like a key for the the Nadi Chakras to open and allow the Sakti power to reunite and realize itself in the ocean that is Maha Sakti Bindu Ananda.